# How to export a VistNetwork plot as a Gephi-readable JSON?

Tags: r, json, shiny, gephi, visnetwork

I would like to export my VistNetwork plot to a JSON format that I can open with Gephi. I use VistNetwork on a Shiny application.

VisNetwork can take a Gephi JSON file as an input, so one would guess it can export one as an output - however, I was not able to find how on the web nor in the VisNetwork documentation.

I have researched the `visExport()` method, but it can only export a PNG, JPG or PDF.

---

**EDIT**: Minimal Reproducible Example (because I'm a new jabroni to SO I forgot to include one)

```
nodes <- data.frame(id = 1:10, label = paste("Label", 1:10), 
   group = sample(c("A", "B"), 10, replace = TRUE))

edges <- data.frame(from = c(2,5,10), to = c(1,2,10))
network <- visNetwork(nodes, edges, height = "400px", width = "100%") 

visNetwork(gephi = 'network.json')
```

Unfortunately, `visNetwork(gephi = 'network.json')` tries to *import* a Gephi file instead of exporting one.

Comment: Try visNetwork(gephi = 'WorldCup2014.json'). If that doesn't work please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Cristoph. I have tried it, but visNetwork(gephi = 'WorldCup2014.json') tries to import a Gephi file and not to export a json.  I have provided an example if an edit of my post.

Comment: Strange. A bug? https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/more.html